# Automatic filling of Tkinter.entry boxes by a separate function

Tags: python, tkinter, self, tkinter-canvas

I have a Tk App that has several entry boxes for number inputs:

```
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.c2_low).grid(column=0,row=2, sticky ='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.c2_high).grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.c3_low).grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.c3_high).grid(column=1,row=3,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.ic4_low).grid(column=0,row=4,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.ic4_high).grid(column=1,row=4,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.nc4_low).grid(column=0,row=5,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.nc4_high).grid(column=1,row=5,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.ic5_low).grid(column=0,row=6,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.ic5_high).grid(column=1,row=6,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.nc5_low).grid(column=0,row=7,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.nc5_high).grid(column=1,row=7,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.n2_low).grid(column=0,row=9,sticky='W')
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable = self.n2_high).grid(column=1,row=9,sticky='W')
```

This is fully working and I can use the number inputs in other functions. However, I want a separate function that fills those entry boxes with generic numbers specified by the function when a 'fill with generic numbers' button is clicked. Is this possible?

EDIT: I have a button for a generic simulation of those numbers mentioned but i'd like the entry boxes to display the numbers I specify.

Comment: Have you done any research? What you're asking is covered in lots of tutorials and tkinter documentation. You merely need to call the `set` method of the variables to whatever values you want.

Comment: It's quite hard to research and specify what you want when you don't know the technical names e.g. set. But this worked, thanks. In future I will look at the documentation more rigorously.

Comment: You don't need to know the technical names, you just need to read the documentation of the classes you're instantiating.

Comment: Also, FWIW, you can omit the use of `self.entry =` here. All you're doing is setting it to `None` over and over again.

Comment: How else would I obtain my StringVar assigned to each Entry?

Comment: well, you can't do it now, so it would be no different. There are many, many questions and answers on stackoverflow related to the question of why `self.entry` (in your case) is always set to `None`. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the Entry widget are directly linked to its control variable, so calling the .set() method on the corresponding StringVar will set the contents of the entry

```
self.c2_low.set("c2_low")
self.c2_high.set(23)   #gets converted to a str automatically
```

then to get the contents back use the .get() method on same variable:

```
try:
    x = int( self.c2_low.get() )
except ValueError:
    NotImplemented   #handle invalid input
```

Also you are calling the .grid() method on the newly created Entries which loses the reference to them later since .grid() returns None, it would probably be easier to use a simple class to group the textvariable together with the Entry widget:

```
class Smart_entry(Tkinter.Entry):
    def __init__(self,master,column,row,content="",name=None):
        self.textvar = Tkinter.StringVar(master,content,name)
        Tkinter.Entry.__init__(self,master,textvariable=self.textvar)
        self.grid(column=column, row=row, sticky="W")

    def get(self):
        return self.textvar.get()

    def set(self,value):
        return self.textvar.set(value)
 # if all the entries are int/float 
 # then handling the conversion in the .get() may be useful
##    def get(self,conv=str):
##        "returns content after converting to specified type, returns None if conversion failed"
##        try:
##            return conv( self.textvar.get() )
##        except ValueError:
##            return None
```